# Macro only works when stepping through

Tags: excel, vba

The following macro only works when i step through it, otherwise it skips a very essential line that deletes a row in a data table. Any suggestions as to why?:/

```
Public table As ListObject    
Public project_code As String
Public Row_Number As Integer
Public sheet As Worksheet
Public myCol As New Collection


Sub UpdateProject_Utveckling()

    Set sheet = Database_Utveckling
    Set table = sheet.ListObjects("Table_Utveckling") ' "Table_Utveckling" is a table 

    project_code = InputSheet_Utveckling.Range("RemoveProject") ' "InputSheet_Utveckling is a worksheet

    DeleteProjectUtveckling table, project_code, myCol, sheet 

    AddProject_Utveckling 'Probably not essential for the Q

    Set myCol = Nothing ' This is a collection

End Sub


Sub DeleteProjectUtveckling(table As ListObject, project_code As String, myCol As Collection, sheet As Worksheet)


    Dim tableColumn As Range

    Set table = Database_Utveckling.ListObjects("Table_Utveckling")
    Set tableColumn = table.ListColumns("Projektkod").DataBodyRange ' "Projektkod" is a column in 

        For Each rng_1 In tableColumn

            If project_code = rng_1 Then

                Row_Number = rng_1.Row
                Exit For

            Else

            End If

        Next rng_1


    sheet.Rows(Row_Number).Delete ' It skips this line when I run it (not when I step through

    End Sub
```

This is driving me crazy! I have tried "DoEvents" and create a separate macro that only handles the "delete" part but with no luck.

Comment: What is `Database_Utveckling`?

Comment: If you put a breakline on that line that is being skipped and run it normally, does it stop there? When you continue the script does the line get deleted?

Comment: "It skips this line" - does it actually skip that line, or does that line do something you don't see?  Have you placed a breakpoint there and run your code?

Comment: If your code doesn't find a match then it still goes ahead and deletes row `Row_Number`, using whatever value happens to already be in that variable.  There's really no reason to use global variables here - you should do your best to avoid them unless absolutely necessary, and in those remaining cases a Static variable is sometimes a better choice.

Comment: It looks like you have a number of unused variables/declarations/assignents. What's the purpose of `myCol` supposed to be?

Comment: @dwirony, my apologies. "Database_Utveckling" is the name of the sheet where the data is stored. It is my database where every row consist of information about a project

Comment: @JNevill, when I run it like that it works as intended every time

Comment: @Tim Williams, thank you for that. I'll make sure to look up the difference between and use it appropriately

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, the purpose of myCol is to store user input from about a project and then transfer it to another sheet (or my database if you will). Another problem I'm currently trying to solve is how to bring them back (to the exact same cell as when the user input were). In that way, the user will be able to "browse" current projects. The main issue here is that the user input consist of 2 section. The first one is straightforward (just cells in a row), but the second one is a 4x5 "matrix" where the user writes in 1 cell per row. I don't know how to store the location in a good way:/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA doesn't "skip" any lines of code, it just doesn't work that way: there's definitely a better, provable explanation - very likely a subtle bug in the logic of the `For Each` loop body that causes `Row_Number` to hold the wrong value.

I would suggest streamlining the loop logic to make it more obviously correct, by leveraging the `ListObject` API and getting rid of the `Row_Number` variable... and moving these global declarations to the only procedure they're actually used and relevant in.

Side note: all these underscores and casing inconsistencies are rather distracting; consider sticking to `PascalCase` for member names and `camelCase` for locals.

> ```
> Set table = Database_Utveckling.ListObjects("Table_Utveckling")
> ```

Why are you re-assigning a parameter you were already given by the caller? Let's rewrite this procedure - extracting that logic into its own scope was a VERY good decision - you want small, specialized procedures that do as little as possible. What are we trying to do? Delete specific rows from a `ListObject`, given a `projectCode`. So our inputs need to include a `ListObject` and a `String` - and we don't need anything else:

```
Private Sub DeleteProjectUtveckling(ByVal table As ListObject, ByVal projectCode As String)

End Sub
```

Note that the procedure is `Private`, since it doesn't need to be `Public`. And since the parameters are all very standard *inputs*, we can pass them `ByVal`.

The first thing we need to do, is find the column in the `table` that might contain the `projectCode`. And since the column may not exist in the provided table, we need to validate that it does.

```
Private Sub DeleteProjectUtveckling(ByVal table As ListObject, ByVal projectCode As String)
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Dim projectCodeColumnIndex As Long
    projectCodeColumnIndex = table.ListColumns("Projektkod").Index

    '...todo...

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    MsgBox "Column 'Projektkod' was not found in table '" & table.Name & "'."
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Next we need to iterate the table rows, and determine if we've found the project code.

```
    Dim currentRow As ListRow
    For Each currentRow In table.ListRows
        If currentRow.Range.Cells(ColumnIndex:=projectCodeColumnIndex).Value = projectCode Then

            '...todo...

        End If
    Next
```

What's nice about a `ListRow`, is that it already knows how to delete itself: we don't need to care for any row number or worksheet rows:

```
currentRow.Delete
```

If the table is guaranteed to not contain any duplicate project codes, then we're done - we can iterate the rest of the rows for no reason, or be smart and bail out immediately like you did.

So the rewritten procedure becomes:

```
Private Sub DeleteProjectUtveckling(ByVal table As ListObject, ByVal projectCode As String)
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Dim projectCodeColumnIndex As Long
    projectCodeColumnIndex = table.ListColumns("Projektkod").Index

    Dim currentRow As ListRow
    For Each currentRow In table.ListRows
        If currentRow.Range.Cells(ColumnIndex:=projectCodeColumnIndex).Value = projectCode Then
            currentRow.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    MsgBox "Column 'Projektkod' was not found in table '" & table.Name & "'."
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

And the calling code becomes:

```
DeleteProjectUtveckling table, project_code
```

Now, that error-handling will work, but if anything unexpected happens in that scope, we'll be getting a misleading and confusing message about a column not being found. Let's fix that.

```
Private Function TryGetColumnIndex(ByVal table As ListObject, ByVal columnName As String, ByRef outIndex) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    outIndex = table.ListColumns(columnName).Index
    TryGetColumnIndex = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

This small function has one single purpose: get the column index, given a table and a column name. It will return `True` if it works, `False` if it doesn't, and when it does work the `outIndex` argument will hold the column index we're after.

Now we can write the row-deletion procedure like this:

```
Private Sub DeleteProjectUtveckling(ByVal table As ListObject, ByVal projectCode As String)
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Dim projectCodeColumnIndex As Long
    If Not TryGetColumnIndex(table, "Projektkod", outIndex:=projectCodeColumnIndex) Then
        MsgBox "Column 'Projektkod' was not found in table '" & table.Name & "'."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim currentRow As ListRow
    For Each currentRow In table.ListRows
        If currentRow.Range.Cells(ColumnIndex:=projectCodeColumnIndex).Value = projectCode Then
            currentRow.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    MsgBox "Unexpected error: " & Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit <~ F9 to place a breakpoint here
    Resume '<~ use for step-through debugging. takes you to the instruction that raised the error
End Sub
```

And just by extracting a small little function, we've turned ambiguous error handling into standard control flow (`If...End If`), and made it clear that any run-time error raised in that procedure is entirely unexpected.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you so much for your highly educational response. I'll go trough this slowly and make sure that I capture all the learning. Much appreciated!

Comment: @OmgAllCaps note that the procedure could rather easily be generalized to delete rows from any `ListObject` when a specified value exists in a specified column (by adding a `ByVal columnName As String` parameter, and replacing the hard-coded `"Projektkod"` with this `columnName` parameter.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. This helped so much and I can use the logic for many of my other macros as well